# Append with date_range() in Python

Tags: python, date, pandas, append

I have a csv file which contains start dates and end dates, with format `dd/mm/yy`.
These are read by :

```
dateparse = lambda x: pnd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%y')
df = pnd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=';',parse_dates=['StartDate','EndDate'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

A sample of the dataframe looks like this:

```
    StartDate   EndDate
0   2015-07-15  2015-07-18
1   2015-06-06  2015-06-08
```

I want to get all the dates listed in these intervals in a column in a new dataframe:

```
    Date
0   2015-07-15
1   2015-07-16
2   2015-07-17
3   2015-07-18
4   2015-06-06  
5   2015-06-07  
6   2015-06-08
```

I use iteratively `date_range(StartDate, EndDate)`, appending each time the result, but I get either an empty array, or something like

```
[[2015-07-15, 2015-07-16, 2015-07-17, 2015-07-18], [ 2015-06-06, 2015-06-07 , 2015-06-08 ]]
```

and I would like

```
[ 2015-07-15, 2015-07-16, 2015-07-17, 2015-07-18, 2015-06-06, 2015-06-07 , 2015-06-08 ]
```

What to do?

Comment: Please show your code of how you are generating the array, you're appending arrays to an array rather than just appending the array contents to an array

Comment: You'll likely just want to use list concatenation if you're trying to add elements from a list to another list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain the ranges together using `itertools.chain` to create your list of dates:

```
from itertools import chain
new_df = pnd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(pnd.date_range(r["StartDate"],r["EndDate"]) 
         for _,r in df.iterrows())), columns=("Date",))
```

Output:

```
        Date
0 2015-07-15
1 2015-07-16
2 2015-07-17
3 2015-07-18
4 2015-06-06
5 2015-06-07
6 2015-06-08
```

Comment: Great solution! Exactly the kind of concise code I wanted to have! Thanks.

Comment: No worries, if you don't want the original dataframe you could create the df in one step